# Wordpress: Always expanded menus in dashboard / Remove minimize menu icons

Tags: wordpress, menu, dashboard, expand

Trying to modify the menu in the dashboard a bit.

I'm trying to remove the toggle option everywhere it's present, and find someway to force the menus to always be expanded, is this possible? (toggle button: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3618143/toggle.png)

Also want to remove the minimize option (which lets you only show icons in the menu bar). I've been able to remove the actual icon, but the functionality is still there (invisible link). So removing the actual image is not the problem, I've managed to remove that, the functionality however is still there. 
(http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3618143/minimize.png)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have the same need: remove the "un/fold" functionality from the WP admin menu bar, to remove clutter, but without tinkering with the source file.

I found out in wp-admin/menu.php that the separators are stored in index 4,59,99.

Here is the function to add to your functions.php

```
    function pxln_remove_menu_items() {

            global $menu;

//an array with menus to remove (use their title)
            $restricted = array(__('Posts'),__('Links'), __('Comments'), __('Media'), __('Separator'));

// keys of the unfolders
            unset($menu[4]);
            unset($menu[59]);
            unset($menu[99]);
            end ($menu);
            while (prev($menu)){
                $value = explode(' ',$menu[key($menu)][0]);
                if(in_array($value[0] != NULL?$value[0]:"" , $restricted)) {
                    unset($menu[key($menu)]);
                }
            }
    }

    add_action('admin_menu', 'pxln_remove_menu_items');
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know where exactly the php file to edit it.
But you can use Firebug from Firefox extension, and find the html code to render the toggle option or separator then delete it.
Example: For separator html code is like this:

```
<li class="wp-menu-separator"><a href="?unfoldmenu=1" class="separator"><br></a></li>
```

Wordpress use cookies to store menu setting, you need to find it and set it manually.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

I didn't mention this, but I hope to achieve this without tinkering with the core of wordpress, I would like to solve it with some code in functions.php, in that way it's safer for future upgrades.

I did find the separator code and removed the background image, but that leaves me with a invisible link, and if I hide the separator all together with display: none, then I of course lose the separator, which I don't like..

Comment: The only way i can think is edit the wordpress core function.